# How to make a UserControl Minimal Download Strategy Compliant

Tags: user-controls, mds, minimal-download-strategy

I have a feature which specifies a custom user control to be added to the AdditionalPageHead delegate control as such:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <Control Id="AdditionalPageHead"
        Sequence="90"
        ControlSrc="~/_CONTROLTEMPLATES/15/CustomUserControl.ascx" /> 
</Elements>
```

The custom user control itself just adds a script block to the page.

When this feature is activated, MDS is disabled on the site collection.

I have set `[assembly: MdsCompliant(true)]` in the AssemblyInfo.cs and also added the attribute to the control.

```
[MdsCompliant(true)]
public partial class CustomUserControl : UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

It looks like I may need to set `SPContext.Current.Web.EnableMinimalDownload` but I'm not sure where that needs to be done.

What else do I need to do to make sure activating this feature won't disable MDS?

Comment: Are you overriding the render method? This is the only time I have seen this pattern disable MDS on the page load.

Comment: Did you ever get this working?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've written a blog post on a few gotcha's when working with MDS

http://steve.thelineberrys.com/gotchas-using-custom-web-parts-and-the-minimal-download-strategy/

My guess is that your user control will need a code behind on it and use the [SPPageContentManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.sppagecontentmanager_members.aspx) to register your script in addition to the mdscompliant(true) attribute.